# Elixir: How can i find product of the sublists in a list?

Tags: list, enums, mapping, elixir

For example, if i have a function argument of findProduct([[1,2,3],[1,5,6]]) how can i figure out the product of the 2 sublists and then add them into a new list with result [6,30]?

Answer (score 2):

```
productFn = fn(list) -> Enum.reduce(list,  &*/2) end 
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 6]]
Enum.map(my_list, productFn) # => [6, 30]
```

If you are not familiar with the `&` operator ([more info here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html#function-capturing)):

```
productFn = fn(list) -> Enum.reduce(list,  &*/2) end
#is equivalent to:
productFn = fn(list) -> Enum.reduce(list, fn(item, acc) -> item * acc end) end
```

And,

```
Enum.map(list, productFn)
is equivalent to:
Enum.map(list, fn(item) -> productFn.(item) end)
```

Comment: Or just `Enum.map(my_list, productFn)` since `&(productFn.(&1))` is the same as `productFn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enum.reduce/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2) to reduce each list with an accumulator, and then return the new list with those two elements:

```
defmodule MyProduct do                       
  def findProduct(list_of_lists) do                   
    Enum.map(list_of_lists, fn(list) -> Enum.reduce(list, fn(x, acc) -> x * acc end) end)                                       
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. They want to know how to do this given a list of lists.

Comment: @JustinWood You are correct, I misread the outer set of brackets (and in particular the "product of two sublists" verbiage. Revised to reflect a list of lists.